# Changing RecyclerView item's width makes the view disappear

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I have the following code:

(setViewHolder is called in Adapter's OnCreateViewHolder)

```
override fun setViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup): BaseViewHolder<Task> {
        return if (isHorizontal) {
            val view =
                LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
                    .inflate(R.layout.horizontal_recycler_item, parent, false)

            // Overriding default width
            val params = view.layoutParams as ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams
            params.width = ((parent.width / 2.15) - params.marginStart - params.marginEnd).toInt()
            view.layoutParams = params

            TaskViewHolder(view)
        } else {
            val view =
                LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
                    .inflate(R.layout.details_list_item, parent, false)
            TaskViewHolder(view)
        }
    }
```

And everything works fine until I refresh the fragment. And that's when the RecyclerView just becomes invisible. However, removing the line, where I set the width, from `setViewHolder` solves my issue.

What causes this?

Comment: I think `parent.width` was 0, maybe you can log it to check.

Comment: Thank you @Hababa, that's the case. Are you aware of any other solutions that would make the view's width 1/3 of the screen?

Comment: You can get the screen width from `context.resources.displayMetrics.widthPixels`, and you can assign it as view's width.

Comment: @Hababa Can you write an answer so that I can mark it as solution?

Comment: OK, I'll upload an answer after a moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it becomes invisible is because you set `width` with `parent.width` directly,

We can not get the true value from `parent.width` when it is not measured.

---

## Here provides two ways you can achieve for your requirement.

### 1. Calculate a View's dimension in layout after measure

```
   view.measure(View.MeasureSpec, View.MeasureSpec)
```

After `view.measure`, we can call `view.measuredWidth` or `view.measuredHeight` to get the true value and calculate the size you want.

```
   (view.measuredWidth / 3).toInt()
```

You just only need to find out what [MeasureSpec](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.MeasureSpec) you need to calculate.

But note that `measure` will caused a heavy-weight in loading, you need to use it carefully.

---

### 2. Set value by the screen size

We can get screen resolution in `DisplayMetric` by `context.resources.displayMetric`, so you can calculate the size you want

```
    (context.resources.displayMetric.width / 3).toInt()
```